# Concerning linearly independent functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ be two linearly independent functions. If we have $g_1(x) f_1(x) = g_2(x) f_2(x)$ for some functions $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$, which could also be linearly independent, then under what conditions can we conclude that $g_1(x) = g_2(x) = 0$?

Comment: What's to prevent $g_1 = f_2/f_1$ and $g_2 = 1$, assuming $f_1 \neq 0$? Or for that matter, what's to prevent the trivial $g_1 = f_2$ and $g_2 = f_1$?

Comment: @user2566092: I think that counts as an answer: there are no conditions on $f_1, f_2$ under which you can conclude $g_1 = g_2 = 0$.